# Fill Down Copy Cells for Same String, Fill Series for different string

Tags: excel

Is there a way to fill down my series based on a changing text string in Col B?

```
Col A Col B
1     stack
1     stack
1     stack
2     Over
2     Over
3     Flow
3     Flow
3     Flow
```

instead of counting 1 2 3, can I count 100000 , 100001, etc.?

Comment: So you want a formula for column A

Comment: Is it always sorted?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes a formula, or an excel feature I am not aware of. Yes sorted alphabetically. Or if there is one where sorting doesnt matter that is a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted, in A1 put your starting number, in A2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS($B$1:B2,$B$1:B2))+MIN($A$1:A1)-1
```

Unsorted, in the first cell put starting number in A1.  Then in A2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:A1,MATCH(B2,$B$1:B1,0)),SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS($B$1:B2,$B$1:B2))+MIN($A$1:A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your answer, if I wanted to starting counting from a number other then 1.

Comment: Like what? things like that need to be in your original question.

Comment: @excelguy see edit, remember to mark correct by clicking the check mark by the answer if it works for you.